# Problems extracting text with PdfBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I try to extract the text from a PDF that was signed by Acrobat Reader, I can't extract it, system freezes until java's memory overflows, but if the PDF was signed by any other program it works normally

```
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFLayoutTextStripper();
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(fileS3);

List<String> pages = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
  pdfStripper.setStartPage(i);
  pdfStripper.setEndPage(i);
                                
  pages .add(pdfStripper.getText(pdfDoc).replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("\n ", "\n"));
}
```

this code freeze here: pdfStripper.getText(pdfDoc)

Comment: Please share an example PDF for which the code above freezes to reproduce the issue. Also please clarify which `PDFLayoutTextStripper` class exactly you mean as there are multiple classes with that name out there.

Comment: I am using this class:
org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper; pdfbox version: pdfbox 2.0.25

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your question to add additional information to it, not answers, as answers are for solutions of the issue. And as asked for above: *Please share an example PDF for which the code above freezes to reproduce the issue.*